# How do I set Ubuntu 12.04.4 up to have buttons for applications, places, and system like older versions of Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, graphics

I hate change for change sake.  My old Ubuntu, no longer supported, had buttons at the top left for applications, places, and system.  It was a good system that worked well for me.
How can I set up the same thing on Ubuntu 12.04.4.

Answer (score 1):

1. Install gnome fallback by run this following commands:

   `sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback`
2. If the proccess is done, don't forget `sudo apt-get update` commands and then logout and press ubuntu icons near login.
3. Switch to gnome fallback
4. Then login to your old ubuntu B).

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

1. First, start Ubuntu software center
2. Search for a package called gnome shell:
   [image: Searching for gnome shell]
3. Install it
4. Logout
5. At the login screen you can now select the icon above and to the right of your username and select Gnome Classic before you logon:
   [image: Gnome Classic Logon]